# Translation to Issachar Jacobson's "נתיב בינה"

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation

Rabbi Issachar Jacobson has a multivolume series on davening called "נתיב בינה". An English translation to the first volume is called "the weekday siddur". Does anyone know if there are English translation to the rest of the series (which is about shabbat davening, yom tov etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that only the three first volumes are available:

- Vol 1: [The Weekday Siddur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0087V0FB8) (Tel Aviv, 1973)
- Vol 2: [The Sabbath service](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007AUXAK) (Tel Aviv, 1981)
- Vol 3: [Meditations on the Siddur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001BM4A8O) (Tel Aviv, 1966)